# OpenCV - undefined reference to 'cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale()' after NDK update

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, opencv, android-ndk

Yesterday I updated my Android Studio included NDK to version `17.0.4754217`and since then I can't run my app anymore. When I tried to rerun the code after the update it gave me the error `ABIs [mips64, armeabi, mips] are not supported for platform. Supported ABIs are [armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64]` so I excluded them from the project in my `app.gradle` file the following way: `abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', /*'armeabi',*/ 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'/*, 'mips', 'mips64'*/`.

However, since then I'm having a problem with the C++-file where I use the OpenCV-function `cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale`.

It always displays the error: `CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o: In function detectAndDisplay(cv::Mat, double, int, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> >, cv::CascadeClassifier&)':
D:\Schule\OpenCV\ARcpp\app\src\main\cpp/native-lib.cpp:158: undefined reference to cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale(cv::_InputArray const&, std::__ndk1::vector<cv::Rect_<int>, std::__ndk1::allocator<cv::Rect_<int> > >&, double, int, int, cv::Size_<int>, cv::Size_<int>)'.`

I call the function like this: `cascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale(frame_gray, sights, scaleFactor, minNeighbours, 0 | CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30));`. The rest of the code is pretty much like shown in the OpenCV-tutorial https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html.

Additionally to the NDK I use CMake and LLDB and my included OpenCV-library is `openCVLibrary320`. Again, all of this worked until I downloaded the mentioned NDK update.

The rest of the error that always appears on building or executing the app is: `Build command failed.
Error while executing process C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {--build D:\Schule\OpenCV\ARcpp\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\arm64-v8a --target native-lib}
[1/1] Linking CXX shared library ..\..\..\..\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\arm64-v8a\libnative-lib.so
FAILED: cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe  --target=aarch64-none-linux-android --gcc-toolchain=C:/Users/chris/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=C:/Users/chris/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot -fPIC -isystem C:/Users/chris/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/aarch64-linux-android -D__ANDROID_API__=21 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -std=c++11 -std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a -nostdlib++ --sysroot C:/Users/chris/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-21/arch-arm64 -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -LC:/Users/chris/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/arm64-v8a -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -shared -Wl,-soname,libnative-lib.so -o ..\..\..\..\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\arm64-v8a\libnative-lib.so CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o  -llog ../../../../src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/libopencv_java3.so -latomic -lm "C:/Users/chris/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/arm64-v8a/libc++_static.a" "C:/Users/chris/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/arm64-v8a/libc++abi.a" && cd ."
clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.`

I`m really lost, hopefully someone knows an answer.

Comment: I am also getting the same error using latest version 3.4.2 for android. Unable to use 'gnustl_static' as arguments because it is not supported by ndk now. Need help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenCV is built with [ANDROID_STL=gnustl_static](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/platforms/android/android.toolchain.cmake#L126). After upgrade, your NDK uses the default **libc++** instead. You can set ANDROID_STL explicitly in your **app/build.gradle**:

```
android { defaultConfig { externalNativeBuild { cmake {
    arguments '-DANDROID_STL=gnustl_static'
} } } }
```

*(see an example [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/android/cmake/build.gradle#L26))*.

Comment: 'gnustl_static' is no longer supported. Is there any workaround?

Comment: @Sar: You can rebuild OpenCV with `c++_shared`, or download an older NDK.

Comment: I have no idea how to rebuild OpenCV with c++_shared. If you can provide any references it will be helpful and thanks for the hint

Answer (score 2):

When linkin opencv with your project executables, you always have to link with the general library **-lopencv_core**. But some packages require additional link flags. For example, 
if you use highgui as in

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
```

you must add opencv_highgui link flag for  : **-lopencv_highgui**.

In you case, CascadeClassifiers are defined in

```
#include "opencv2/objdetect.hpp"
```

and thus requires a link with opencv_objdetect **-lopencv_objdetect**.

The solution is to add the link flag **-lopencv_objdetect** when compiling.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, unfortunately I don't really know how to do this in Android Studio.

Comment: I just noticed that I already `#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>` included in my C++-code. Is that what you meant? Because adding/removing it makes no difference considering the above mentioned error.

Answer (score 1):

A more complete answer for all the seekers out there. Using OpenCV prebuilt ***static libraries*** in your project with a native component.

This is what I have for the `build.gradle`:

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 21
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            cppFlags "-fexceptions -std=gnu++11"
            arguments '-DANDROID_STL=gnustl_static'
        }
    }
    ndk {
        // Specifies the ABI configurations of your native
        // libraries Gradle should build and package with your APK.
        abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86'
        stl = "gnustl_shared"
    }
}
```

This is the CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(OPENCV_LIBRARIES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_NDK_ABI_NAME}/libopencv_video.a
                     ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_NDK_ABI_NAME}/libopencv_imgproc.a
                     ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_NDK_ABI_NAME}/libopencv_core.a
                     ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_NDK_ABI_NAME}/libopencv_highgui.a
                     ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_NDK_ABI_NAME}/libtbb.a
                     ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_NDK_ABI_NAME}/libcpufeatures.a
                     )

if (${ANDROID_ABI} STREQUAL "x86")
    set(OPENCV_LIBRARIES ${OPENCV_LIBRARIES}
                         ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_NDK_ABI_NAME}/libippiw.a
                         ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_NDK_ABI_NAME}/libippicv.a
                         ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_NDK_ABI_NAME}/libittnotify.a
                         )
    set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippicv.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippiw.a")
endif()

if (${ANDROID_ABI} STREQUAL "armeabi-v7a")
    set(OPENCV_LIBRARIES ${OPENCV_LIBRARIES}
                         ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_NDK_ABI_NAME}/libtegra_hal.a
                         )
endif()
```

(then use `${OPENCV_LIBRARIES}` for your `target_link_libraries`)

Answer (score 1):

The first comment on this [link](https://answers.opencv.org/question/201415/opencv-error-undefined-reference-to-cvcascadeclassifierdetectmultiscale/) can save you many hours which I copy past below:

"I had similar issue. In turned out that you got to use similar Android NDK as one that was used to build OpenCV Android SDK, that in case of versions ~3.4 is Android NDK 10. Recently, OpenCV Android SDK 4.0.1 have been released and it works with the newest NDK version (19 at the time)."

At the time of this post, you can find the release [4.1.2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/4.1.2/opencv-4.1.2-android-sdk.zip/download). You can check if there's a latest release on this [link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/).

After you select your latest version, in this case 4.1.2, download the file [opencv-4.1.2-android-sdk.zip](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/4.1.2/opencv-4.1.2-android-sdk.zip/download), unzip it and copy the sdk/native folder to yourprojectfolder/your-app/src/sdk/.

You're ready to roll.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using mix with [this](https://github.com/quickbirdstudios/opencv-android) OpenCV + contrib lib (opencv4_1_0_contrib) and [official](https://opencv.org/releases/) Java OpenCV classes (4.3). Successfully run official OpenCV [FaceDetection](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/samples/android/face-detection) example on Android 9.

---

### Some usefull code:

App level build.gradle:

```
android{defaultConfig{
//...
externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions"
                abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
                //I import OpenCV as module and provide it path to CMake
                arguments "-DOpenCV_DIR=/" + rootProject.projectDir.path + "/sdk/native"
             }
        }
}}

externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
            version "3.10.2"
        }
    }
```

My CMakeLists.txt:

```
# Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build the native library.
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

#Add OpenCV 4 lib
include_directories(${OpenCV_DIR}/jni/include) #Path from gradle to OpenCV Cmake
add_library( lib_opencv SHARED IMPORTED )
set_target_properties(lib_opencv PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${OpenCV_DIR}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopencv_java4.so)

#Add Your Native Lib
add_library(native-lib SHARED native-lib.cpp)
add_library(detection_based_tracker SHARED detectionbasedtracker_jni.cpp)

#Add&Link Android Native Log lib with others libs
find_library(log-lib log)
target_link_libraries(detection_based_tracker lib_opencv ${log-lib})
```

---

NDK version was 21.0.611669.
Also I don't use arguments for CMake like `-DANDROID_STL=gnustl_static`.